# Angular HttpClient - getting progress messages from server before the final response

Tags: angular, server

I'm using the Angular HttpClient service to call a web service that could take several minutes to complete. I would like to receive progress status (including a percentage and a message) to display on the browser before the final response. Does Angular have a mechanism to support this?

I've tried sending a 100 status from the server with the progress information as part of the header but that doesn't work. The HttpClient supports the ProgressEvent api but that's only for tracking upload/download of a multi-part request.

I could create another service that I would then poll on a timer, but is there another more standard way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like create a BehaviorSubject for the messages in the web service, and wire it up in your components to respond to. You just send the message in the BehaviourSubject. Then when you want it to disappear send a blank message. Take a look at what RxJs brings to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables)

> Observables provide support for passing messages between publishers
>   and subscribers in your application. Observables offer significant
>   benefits over other techniques for event handling, asynchronous
>   programming, and handling multiple values.

Update

You can use a timer which is a primary option if above not working.

```
const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      if (CHECK IF DONE) {
           clearInterval(intervalId);
    // DO THE THING YOU WANT AFTER COMPLETE
      }
      else {
        // GET PROGRESS
      }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: I'm using the HttpClient post and request methods to reach out to a in-house application server (written in C++). The server receives the request and dispatches a response. For a single request, I can get a single response in my Angular app. That works fine. What I'm trying to do is receive responses from the server to get progress info. If the server sends a response with HTTP status 200, the client can't receive any more responses.

Comment: @DalbirSingh : If you have another endpoint to get the progress, timer is another option.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think angular comes with a standard way to do this.

In my opinion looks like you will need to do two requests to the server

- First, the request to the endpoint that actually runs the long running process. This endpoint will start the process on a separate thread and inmediately return an id of that process to the client to check the status
- With the process id returned from the first request, you can call the check-status endpoint. You can set an interval to check progress and update the UI.